# Como habilitar o Flash Player no navegador via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

Há alguma maneira de habilitar o Flash Player via Javascript no navegador como [nesse link](https://helpx.adobe.com/br/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html)?

Comment: @jbueno mais até o https://play.spotify.com/browse web solicita.

Comment: Você ta querendo forçar o navegador do usuário a executar o flash, independente se ele quer que execute ou nao? Isso é altamente invasivo.

Comment: ativar add-ons via javascript geralmente não e um idea boa, maioria dos browsers bloqueando isso por segurança próprio.

Comment: Neste link  ele pede para mim baixar o Flash, não para ativar o flash.

Comment: @diegofm gostaria de mandar uma mensagem avisando pelo menos que ele precisa ativar para executar uma função.

Answer (score 8):

Não há uma maneira oficial de habilitar o Flash usando somente o Javascript, se descobrirem como fazer isto possivelmente será tratado como um problema de segurança.

Sobre o [`play.spotify.com/browse`](http://play.spotify.com/browse), ele pede claramente para o usuário habilitar, *manualmente*, isto não requer JS, mas sim a interpretação do navegador ao clicar em `https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/`,

Utilizar isto:

```
<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Clique aqui</a>
```

Vai mostrar uma notificação, **dependendo do navegador**, [teste isto aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/wtzbbhLb/show/), como esta aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O Chrome, por padrão, já possui o Flash instalado e atualizado por padrão, porém desligado, *salvo caso que o usuário remova manualmente*. Demais navegadores podem nem ter acesso ao Flash, este mesmo link irá apontar para a página de download do Flash.